# Does the JVM fix my inefficient code by storing the results of similar method calls within the same method?

Tags: java, jvm

Given the code

```
if (linkedHashMap.get(string) == null) { 
  linkedHashMap.put(string, object);
} else { 
  linkedHashMap.get(string).increment();
}
```

Does the Interputer/JVM decide that : `linkedHashMap.get(string)` is used twice and and therefore Assign a variable for this call Or does it simply do the exact same call twice inefficiently?

Comment: I don’t have a source to support this, but I’d say: no. The JVM can’t know whether the method has the same behaviour and the same return value  both times it is called. If you debug a minimal example and set a breakpoint to `LinkedHashMap.get`, you’ll see that the method is actually called twice from your code.

Comment: No.  A call is never eliminated (with a few special case exceptions).

Comment: @HotLicks do you have a reference for that?

Comment: @davmac - Do you have a reference to the contrary?  I spent about 5 years of my life implementing and supporting Java interpreters and JITCs for IBM.

Comment: @davmac - The main rule is that side-effects cannot be changed.  Without inlining `get` (or using an Ouija Board to understand what `get` does), the interpreter/JITC cannot be sure that it does not have a side-effect in the second call that would not have occurred in the first call, therefore the second call cannot be eliminated.

Comment: *"without inling get"*, yeah, well, that's what the JIT does. So if this method gets really hot and C2 kicks in then there's some chance that this actually gets eliminated, depending on the complexity of the `.get()` implementation. Of course the only way to find out is to actually try it and look at the opto-assembly

Comment: @HotLicks I don't have a reference to the contrary, but then I never made any claim either way; you claimed that "a call is never eliminated" and I asked if you had a reference. In regards to your more recent comment, I don't understand why you seem to discount inlining the `get` method.

Comment: @davmac - Inlining won't help if the JITC cannot discern that the hashtable is not being modified between calls.  That's a pretty tall order.

Comment: You could check it by placing debug line in `hashcode()` method of your key (ofcourse custom key to validate)

Comment: @HotLicks the two calls to the `get` method are literally one after the other, I don't see how determining that the hashtable is not being modified in between them is difficult. Discounting the 'true' case, OPs code is equivalent to `if (linkedHashMap.get(string) != null) linkedHashMap.get(string).increment();`.

Comment: @davmac - The JITC doesn't know that `get` itself doesn't modify the hashtable.  It does not know what a hashtable is.  There is no property in Java to tell the JITC that `get` is idempotent.

Comment: @HotLicks If the method is inlined it probably turns into something like (1) get hashcode, (2) use that as in index into an array, (3) look at that point and onwards to see if the key is present (4) return the paired value if so. None of these steps modify anything (except perhaps getting the hashcode, this would need to be checked in the same manner), so it follows that the same sequence executed twice in a row should give the same result. It may be the JITC in most/all Java implementations don't do this, but they certainly _could_. A JITC can annotate methods any way it likes.

Comment: What I said is that there's no annotation in **Java**.  Eg, there's no *idempotent* modifier that one can specify on a method.  So the JITC cannot inherently know that `get` is idempotent.  As to inlining `get`, the source I have for LinkedHashMap shows about 20 lines of code, three `if` statements, and one `for` loop, making it a possible candidate for inlining but likely too difficult to analyze for idempotence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given a sufficiently advanced JIT and a sufficiently trivial implementation of `get()` - and the `equals()` called by it - it might get optimized away at some point. But there are no guarantees.

The implementation details of `get()` are important because it could either include memory visibility effects (atomics, locks) or have a complexity that exceeds the compiler's ability to perform redundant code elimination.

E.g. I would guess that a map generated by `Collections.singletonMap` is easy enough to optimize. But a `ConcurrentHashMap` certainly is not due to its use of volatiles and locks.

But in the end the only way to get certainty is to look at the generated assembly for the method in question, after it became hot enough to have its callees inlined be JITed.

Comment: This answers the purpose of the question, The example was just the piece of code that triggered my query, I think its fair to say that (at least in early stages of development) these multi method calls can help me keep track of what im doing in a rough mock up but for cleanness should be refactored out.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as an Interputer. The just-in-time compiler might recognize the duplication, but only if the methods being invoked are simple enough to be inlined, which is probably not the case for HashMap.get. That said, the redundant lookup takes less than a microsecond, so unless the code is executed millions of times each second, the effects on performance will not be significant.

A simple way to avoid redundant lookups (that also works nicely with ConcurrentMaps) would be

```
linkedHashMap.merge(string, 1, Integer::sum);
```

Comment: *There is no such thing as an Interputer.*  What do you think the thing is in the JVM which interprets bytecodes that have not (yet) been JITCed?  (OK, it's properly spelled "interpreter", but I don't think that was your point.)

Comment: The spelling actually was part of the point. The other is that performance critical code is JITCed, so the interpreter does not matter.